# Is there a shortcut for tag synonymity when a software project has been renamed?

Tags: support, tag-synonym-process

OpenERP has been renamed to Odoo. I started adding [odoo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/odoo) to [openerp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openerp) questions, but then I [got the suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17690257/insert-order-using-webservice-with-openerp/25019226?noredirect=1#comment38916035_25019226) that it would be better to create tag synonymity. This has been suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/openerp/synonyms).

But given that the only person with enough rep to vote up a synonymity doesn't even have any rep in [odoo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/odoo) it can take years before this tag synonym will ever be accepted.

Is there a shortcut or do we really have to wait for four people with 2k5+ rep and answer score 5 on the [odoo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/odoo) tag?

The synonym-request on meta: [Create tag synonymity between OpenERP and Odoo](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267190/create-tag-synonymity-between-openerp-and-odoo)

Comment: The "shortcut" is to request a synonym be created on [metaso], preferably using the [meta-tag:synonym-request] tag.

Comment: Ok! http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267190/create-tag-synonymity-between-openerp-and-odoo

Answer (score 1):

Judging by your comment, @Al E's Comment might be acceptable as an answer:

> The "shortcut" is to request a synonym be created on Meta Stack Exchange, preferably using the synonym-request tag.

(Though perhaps nowadays that should be [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com).)