# Synoymise [openerp] and [odoo]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

OpenERP [has been renamed to Odoo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odoo). It would be nice if the [odoo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/odoo) and [openerp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openerp) tags became synonyms.

There is already a [request for that](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/openerp/synonyms) but at this point not a single person can vote it up now, so it could take a long time before this will happen, unless a moderator makes it happen.